# Redirect permanent with additional params

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, permanent

My goal is to redirect from
**/kontaktaufnehmen/kontakt.html** to **/auftragsverwaltung/kontakt/?type=1**
and the parameters must be added to the new path.

I tried

```
Redirect permanent /kontaktaufnehmen/kontakt.html /auftragsverwaltung/kontakt/?type=1
```

but the parameters are not added to the redirected path.
Without `?type=1` the parameter will be added.

Comment: Which are the parameters?

Comment: the other parameters doesnt matter, because all parameters must be added to the url. Example: /kontaktaufnehmen/kontakt.html?test=1 must be redirected to /auftragsverwaltung/kontakt/?type=1&test=1

Comment: They do matter because they seem to be in a query. If that is the case, the flags should include `QSA`. Example [L,QSA]. That way the incoming query will be appended to the query added in the rule. I am just guessing though. It will help to see the rules you have now and one example of a complete incoming URL to have a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !type=1
RewriteRule ^/?kontaktaufnehmen/kontakt.html /auftragsverwaltung/kontakt/?type=1 [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=1
RewriteRule ^/?kontaktaufnehmen/kontakt.html /auftragsverwaltung/kontakt/ [L,R=301]
```

The important thing here is the `QSA` flag, which means whatever query string that's already there gets appended. The mod_alias directive `Redirect` won't do this for you. The second rule is simply a redirect because it sees that the `type=1` query string is already there so it won't add another.